# Java creation of new set too slow

Tags: java, set

I have this program where it have some recursive function similar to this:

```
public static void lambda(HashSet<Integer> s){
    if(end(s)){
        return;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<w;i++){
        HashSet<Integer> p = (HashSet) s.clone();
        p.addAll(get_next_set());
        do_stuff_to(p);
        lambda(p);
    }
}
```

What I'm doing is union every set with the set s. And run lambda on each one of the union.
I run a profiler and found the c.clone() operation took 100% of the time of my code. Are there any way to speed this up considerably?

Comment: "100% of the time of my code". Really? Are you sure that measurement includes whatever get_next_set and do_stuff_to do?  And how many wall clock seconds do these 100% represent? Is it really too slow for your needs?

Comment: also .clone() is probably not the best way to do this, it almost guaranteed is not doing what you think it is doing. hint: it isn't actually making copies of the objects in the set, only copies of the references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I did to speed up everything, this way I never have to create new sets.

```
public static void lambda(HashSet<Integer> s){
    if(end(s)){
        return;
    }
    ArrayList<Integer> diff = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for(int i=0;i<w;i++){
        //an array version of the next set, it is pre-computed
        int[] a = get_next_set_array();
        for(int j=0;j<a.length;j++){
            if(!s.contains(a[j])){
               diff.add(a[j]);
            }
        }
        s.addAll(diff);
        do_stuff_to(s);
        s.removeAll(diff);
        diff.clear();
        lambda(p);
    }
}
```

On average this is much faster, and the program spend roughly the same amount of time on the addAll and removeAll.

Answer (score 0):

When you are cloning, what are you really trying to do, maybe you don't need to do a complete cloan?

Your best bet at improving the performance of your lambda function is to extend  HashSet and overide the clone definition with a custom one that is particular to your situation...

I don't know of anyother way to really help with out more information unfortunatly.

Comment: I don't think that would do much good. He needs a full copy of all set elements, and the default clone is already quite fast (it is faster than the copy-constructor for example).

Comment: I don't really know what the purpose of the clone, if he can give more information then we could suggest an alternative, also there might be special properties that he knows about the HashSet that can help desgin a faster clone,

The current clone implementation is just a new HashSet(set), so there might be a faster way

Answer (score 0):

If I get it right you try to do the following:

```
lambda(Set p) {
    lambda(p + further elements);
}
```

You can avoid cloning p e.g. by reimplementing a list and using the Nodes as parameters for lambda:

```
class Node {
    int content;
    Node next;

    Node(int content, Node next) {
        this.content = content;
        this.next = next;
    }
}

void lambda(Node set) {
    // add new elements to front
    Node newSet = set;

    for(Integer i : new_elements() ) {
        newSet = new Node(i, newSet);
    }

    lambda(newSet);
    // Observe that set is not modified by adding new elements
}
```

This is a low-level-solution and you would have to implement a slow sequential search/find-algorithm (if you rely on unique elements in the set), yet in my experience such a stack is a good solution for most recursive algorithms.

Comment: This does in fact speed up what I'm doing for small data. But the sequential search will dominate and use more time than the original when the data gets really large, so it become infeasible.